# Texturing a Sphere in OpenGL 3+

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to wrap a 1024*512 image around a sphere.

Here is my code: (not all shown)

in main.cpp:

```
struct Vertex {

    GLdouble position[3];
    GLfloat color[3];
    GLfloat textureUV[2];
};

void SetupGemetry() {

    //Allocate 4 VBOs
    glGenBuffers(4, vbo);

    }

//Setting the current Buffer.
void setBuffer(int buffer_no, int no_vertices, Vertex *vertices_array)
{

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[buffer_no]);

    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, no_vertices * sizeof ( struct Vertex ), vertices_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glVertexAttribPointer ( ( GLuint ) 0, 3, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, sizeof ( struct Vertex ), ( const GLvoid* ) 
    offsetof(struct Vertex ,position) );        

    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );

    glVertexAttribPointer ( ( GLuint ) 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof ( struct Vertex ), ( const GLvoid* )
    offsetof(struct Vertex,color) );

    //Textute Handling
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
    glVertexAttribPointer(( GLuint ) 2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(struct Vertex),(const GLvoid* )offsetof(struct Vertex ,texture));
```

}

now in my Sphere.cpp (here I load the *.bmp file)

```
GLuint Sphere::loadBMP_custom(const char * imagepath)
{
    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    unsigned char header[54]; // Each BMP file begins by a 54-bytes header
    unsigned int dataPos;     // Position in the file where the actual data begins
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned int imageSize;   // = width*height*3
    // Actual RGB data
    unsigned char * data;
    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(imagepath,"rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Image could not be opened\n"); 
        return 0;
    }
    //Checking the header file
    if ( fread(header, 1, 54, file)!=54 )
    { // If not 54 bytes read : problem
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }
    if ( header[0]!='B' || header[1]!='M' )
    {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    dataPos    = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize  = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    width      = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    height     = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);
    // Some BMP files are misformatted, guess missing information
    if (imageSize==0)    imageSize=width*height*3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
    if (dataPos==0)      dataPos=54; // The BMP header is done that way

    // Create a buffer
    data = new unsigned char [imageSize];

    // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
    fread(data,1,imageSize,file);

    //Everything is in memory now, the file can be closed
    fclose(file);

    //OpenGL Part
    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    // Give the image to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}

void Sphere::SetupShaders_sphere(void){

    // Read our shaders into the appropriate buffers
    sphere_vertexsource = filetobuf_sphere("vertex_shader_2.vert");
    sphere_fragmentsource = filetobuf_sphere("fragment_shader_2.frag");

    //Assign our handles a "name" to new shader objects 
    sphere_vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    sphere_fragmentshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Associate the source code buffers with each handle
    glShaderSource(sphere_vertexshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&sphere_vertexsource, 0);
    glShaderSource(sphere_fragmentshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&sphere_fragmentsource, 0);

    //Setting them up by compiling, attaching and linking them!
    glCompileShader(sphere_vertexshader);
    glCompileShader(sphere_fragmentshader);

    sphere_shaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(sphere_shaderprogram, sphere_vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(sphere_shaderprogram, sphere_fragmentshader);

    glBindAttribLocation(sphere_shaderprogram, 0, "in_Position"); 
    glBindAttribLocation(sphere_shaderprogram, 1, "in_Color");

    glLinkProgram(sphere_shaderprogram);
    glUseProgram(sphere_shaderprogram);

}
```

now my Fragment and Vertex Shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexUV;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP_matrix;

void main(){

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP_matrix * vec4(in_Position,1);

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 UV;

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;

void main(){

    // Output color = color of the texture at the specified UV
    color = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgb;
}
```

How do I convert the image file coordinates (UV) to 3D ones? How do I pass them the my vertex shader? (well I know how to pass data to vertex, I basically mean how do I convert the 2D image file into 3D?) for example I found this nice tutorial

www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

That says : "Well, we’ll have to do the exact same thing here, but instead of giving a buffer (R,G,B) triplets, we’ll give a buffer of (U,V) pairs."

```
// Two UV coordinatesfor each vertex. They were created with Blender. You'll learn shortly how to do this yourself.
static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = {
    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f,
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f,
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f,
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f,
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.000004f, 1.0f-0.671870f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f,
    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f
};
```

Do I have to use blender?
I found this http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texturing_a_Sphere#2D_Texture_Mapping_a_Sphere
but still i can't understand it

Answer (score 1):

> How do I convert the image file coordinates (UV) to 3D ones?

You don't. The texture does not make your geometry. You need to supply the coordinates for the sphere as well. No you don't have to use Blender, that was just used to export some vertex data (positions, normals and texture coordinates) for later use. So in addition to the UV buffer, there should also be a *position* and a *normal* buffer.

Comment: I have the sphere's position buffer, and normal too! the Problem is the UV buffer. I have no idea how too implement it. The tutorials I found are not simple enough for me. When you say "You need to supply the coordinates for the sphere as well" I already did that. I am passing the position coordinates to the vertex shader.

Comment: I don't see your problem then. You're already passing the UV coordinates. It's the very last glVertexAttribPointer call in your main.cpp snippet (well it's not entirely correct, you have only 2 elements per texcoord, not 3). How about you upload your source code written so far somewhere? That way I can try to reproduce your problem, fix your code, so that you can learn from it.

Comment: I am not passing the UV yet, because I have not calculated them yet. I have the last glVertexAttribPointer activated like you said but I am not passing anything yet, cause I don't understand how UV coordinates are related to the colours of the image I am trying to wrap on the sphere

Comment: @TestTest: UV coordinates usually are not calculated (except for a few cases), but applied by some artist. A texture is an image. The lower left corner of the image is at (0,0), the upper right corner at (1,1). Each vertex of a triangle gets assigned a 2 values in the range [0,1], which make the triangle sample from the texture.

Comment: "UV coordinates usually are not calculated" so how opengl knows them?

Comment: @TestTest: By you supplying OpenGL with them, coming from some 3D modell data. I repeat: An artist creates the texture mapping using a UV editor in some 3D modeller, then saves the UV coordinates together with the rest of the model.

Answer (score 1):

The question "how do I convert the image file coordinates (UV) to 3D ones?" sounds reversed. You should be asking "how do I convert sphere coordinates (3D) to image coordinates (UV)?  The tutorial sample used Blender to create a static array of UV data. If you are calculating the vertices of the sphere, you need to calculate the UV coordinates at the same time and store them in the Vertex struct.  Or if you have a pre-calculated set of static sphere coordinates, you need to calculate a similar set of UV coordinates.  The idea is to take the 3D data and pass it through a mapping function that returns U,V coordinates for which pixel of the texture gets used for that 3D point.

The easiest calculation is one that uses polar coordinates (azimuth, altitude) and maps that to U,V range.  If the sphere 3D vertices are being calculated, chances are the algorithm already uses polar coordinates and calls trig functions to get the X,Y,Z.

The opengl.org link mentions that'cubemap' is the preferred approach for texturing a sphere.  "For best result, use a cubemap. The problem with applying a 2D texture is that when you wrap a 2D texture onto a sphere, the top and bottom area of the sphere, the texture looks squeezed."

The 2D map you propose will always have distortions when wrapped around a sphere or other 3D curves.  It is possible to adjust the U,V mapping algorithm to minimize the effects or hide the seams in outside of the primary line of sight, but it the sphere is rotated they will show up somewhere.

Comment: This is what I don't get. I can easily calculate the UV coordinated and store them like you said in my Vertex structure, and pass them to the vertex shader. But the thing I don't get is how the image is related to all these UV coordinate thing, I mean the colors etc etc

Comment: @TestTest: Maybe this video makes it clear. Left pane is the texture, with lower left corner of image being (U,V)=(0,0) and upper right corner being (U,V)=(1,1), Right pane is some geometry, in this case a single triangle. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0kP_YA5oE0